# Difficulty understanding decompression with LZW algorithm

Tags: algorithm, compression, information-theory, lzw

I compressed the following message: "ababcbababaaaaaaa" using LZW compression algorithm.

With a=1;b=2;c=3 i get the following message : "1 2 4 3 5 8 1 10 11 1", which matches the result my professor got in our exercise notes.

However, when i try decompressing the message, i get the following sequence of events:

```
Current: a  ; Next: b  ; Output: a  ; AddToDict: ab=4;

Current: b  ; Next: a  ; Output: b  ; AddToDict: ba=5;

Current: ab ; Next: c  ; Output: ab ; AddToDict: abc=6;

Current: c  ; Next: ba ; Output: c  ; AddToDict: cb=7;

Current: ba ; Next: 8? ; Output: ?  ; AddToDict: ?;
```

As you can see, my issue is that i dont have 8(which is supposed to be "bab") in the dictionary yet.

What am i doing wrong?

The complete dictionary gained from compression is

(1=a;2=b;3=c;4=ab;5=ba;6=abc;7=cb;8=bab;9=baba;10=aa;11=aaa;12=aaaa)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be careful! The first column is the "current sequence", but the second column is the "next character" (not the "next sequence"). Hence, you have a **mistake** when writing "next: ba". By the way, up to the the last row is correct:

```
Current: ba  ; Next: b   ; Output: ba   ; AddToDict: bab = 8;   // here is 5
Current: bab ; Next: a   ; Output: bab  ; AddToDict: baba = 9;  // here you can find 8
Current: a   ; Next: a   ; Output: a    ; AddToDict: aa = 10;   // here is 1 
Current: aa  ; Next: a   ; Output: aa   ; AddToDict: aaa = 11;  // here is 10
Current: aaa ; Next: a   ; Output: aaa  ; AddToDict: aaaa = 12; // here is 11
Current: a   ; Next: #   ; Output: a    ; #                     // here is 1
```

Answer (score 2):

You're thinking in terms of `Current Next`. I view decoding in terms of `Previous Current`. So be aware when reading this answer that `Current` is the current number from the message (see the column labeled `Current` in the table below, and observe that it contains the message to be decoded).

Note that by my definition, the first code of the message has to be treated as a special case, since there is no `Previous` code. The first code in a message is always a single letter code, and no dictionary entry is created when processing that code.

For all other codes in the message, there are two possibilities:

- Typical: the `Current` code has a dictionary entry. In this case, the output is the dictionary string for the `Current` code. The new dictionary string is formed by taking the string for the `Previous` code, and appending the first letter of the string for the `Current` code.
- Quirky: the `Current` code does not yet have a dictionary entry. In this case, the output is the string for the `Previous` code, plus the first letter of the string for the `Previous` code. The new dictionary string is formed by taking the string for the `Previous` code, and appending the first letter of the string for the `Previous` code.

With that in mind, here's how the message is decoded:

```
Previous  Current  Output    Dictionary  Type
    -        1       a        -          special
    1        2       b        4: ab      typical
    2        4       ab       5: ba      typical
    4        3       c        6: abc     typical
    3        5       ba       7: cb      typical
    5        8       bab      8: bab     quirky: dict[5] is "ba" plus first letter of dict[5] is "b" means dict[8] is "bab"
    8        1       a        9: baba    typical
    1       10       aa      10: aa      quirky
   10       11       aaa     11: aaa     quirky
   11        1       a       12: aaaa    typical
```

Notice in the quirky case, the output and the new dictionary entry are the same. They are generated using information exclusively from the `Previous` code. The `Current` code is ignored when decoding the quirky case, and the new dictionary entry is the entry for the `Current` code.